# Retrieve Custom Field from FireStore android

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Hello i want to retrieve Field "ID" under collection "Favorite" from all user.

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Favorite")
    .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){ 
        @Override 
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) { 
                for (DataSnapshot dst : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) { 
                //Key stores KjfLmUnPUaWeYDETp04 and PlamHmUnPUaWeYDETp04 String key = dst.getKey(); Log.d("Idsssss", key);
                }
            }
    });
```

[image]

```
            String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
            FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
            CollectionReference favoriteRef = rootRef.collection("usersFavorite").document(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).collection("Favorite");
            favoriteRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            Log.d("TAGTAGTAG", document.getString("id"));
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

But it doesn't work i want to get all document ID from all document, 
And when i want to retrieve document ID it retrieve only the first ID (because its the same ID for user ) with this command 
                                                String id = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("usersFavorite").document(firebaseAuth.getUid()).collection("Favorite").document(firebaseAuth.getUid()).getId();

Done and my path is usersFavorite => UserId => Favorite => Random ID => then List of favorite that i want to retrieve ID's

This is my firebase structure
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3T9Y7.png)

Comment: Please post what have you tried so far. You can retrieve all the children once.

Comment: FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Favorite").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot dst : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            //Key stores KjfLmUnPUaWeYDETp04 and PlamHmUnPUaWeYDETp04
                            String key = dst.getKey();
                            Log.d("Idsssss", key);

Comment: I don't think the above stucture is for Firebase Realtime Database.

Comment: It's FireStore not realTime database

Comment: Then you provided the code of Firebase Realtime Database

Comment: @MondherEssid Please provide a more detailed database structure so I can update my answer with the correct reference. I need to see the root collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sharing a screenshot with a Firestore database while you are trying to use code that gets data from a Firebase Realtime database and this will **not** work since Cloud Firestore and Firebase Realtime database are two different products. To get ids of those documents, please use the following lines of code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference favoriteRef = rootRef.collection("usersFavorite").document(uid).collection("Favorite");
favoriteRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                Log.d("TAG", document.getString("id"));
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage());
        }
    }
});
```

The result in the logcat will be all values of the `id` property printed out.